# Why does $\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = -\sin^{-1}(x) + C$ and not $\cos^{-1}(x) + C?$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Since $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arccos(x) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, it seems odd that $\displaystyle\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = -\arcsin(x) + C$. Why is this the case?

Comment: What is the relation between $\arcsin (x)$ and $\arccos (x)$?

Comment: @kolja I don't know. They're both inverse trig functions.

Comment: This is a good question. $\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(x)$, so we see that they do differ by a constant of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with the mathematical proof for the given integration - simply by substituting $x=sin(t)$ we get the integration result.

Now if we substitute $x=cos(t)$ we get the integration $I = cos^{-1}(x) + C$. Both the solutions are right because $cos^{-1}(x)$ and $sin^{-1}(x)$ are linearly related by the relation $$cos^{-1}(x) + sin^{-1}(x) = \pi/2$$ 
So by varying constant $C$ every time we get the correct integration result.

Comment: Thank you! This helps.